# How to add multiple Icons into QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, qlistwidgetitem, qicon

I am setting up an user manager and i need to implement User statue policy. I have a list of users in QTreeWidget and each user has its own QTreeWidgetItem. User has some atributes (ban, hasPassword...) and I want to show it instantly in list.

```
bool cUserManager::addUser2TreeWidget(cUser* user) {
if (!user) return false;
QTreeWidgetItem* item_user = 0;
item_user = new QTreeWidgetItem(item_AVAILABLE);
item_user->setCheckState(0,Qt::Unchecked);
item_user->setText(0, user->getName());
QWidget *userStateIcons = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
hLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton(QIcon(PATH_ICON_BAN),""));
hLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton(QIcon("PATH_ICON_LOCK"),""));
userStateIcons->setLayout(hLayout);
ui.treeUsers->setItemWidget(item_user,1,userStateIcons);
return true;
```

Output:

[image]

I expect to see the:
Checkbox, Icon(if user is banned), Icon(if user has password),Icon(if user has admin rights), text (User name).
With buttons it is very hard to style it(set width, height, flat button...). Is there any proper and easier way to just insert only pixmap?
Thank you for advises and tips.

Comment: You should show your attempt first

Comment: Ok, I try hard.

Comment: What have you tried? Try to keep the code as minimal as possible. Perhaps you should first try something very simple, like just showing a single item with an icon. Then add columns with more data.

Comment: Question updated.